# Identifying whether Victorian Historical Death Record belongs to ancestor?

Tags: death-records, australia, 1890s, victoria

I am seeking verification of whether a Victorian Historical Death Record may be for Charles Templeman from my tree.

- Born England 1815
- Married Jane Forrester
- Had 3 children

  - Emma born England 1832
  - Clara born Victoria Australia 1849
  - Jane born Victoria abt 1854

Victorian Online Historical has a Death record of a Charles Templeman

- Father's Name Jno
- Mother's name Emily WILKIE
- Death Place Northcote Convent
- Registration Year 1892
- Age 80

What additional evidence will support or contradict the assertion that they are the same person?

Comment: Do you have a web address for "Victorian Online Historical"?  Is it the same as "Victorian Historical Death Record"?  It's not easily findable for those not familiar with what the site(s) is/are.  With a link, others will be able to find the same source.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they could be the same person. On the other hand, they might not be. The question that you need to consider is "What additional evidence will support or contradict the assertion that they are the same person?" You might like to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Since Northcote Convent was conducted by the Little Sisters of the Poor for the indigent elderly, you might begin searching at <http://www.littlesistersofthepoor.org.au/#!our-life/vstc16=melbourne/vstc10=our-history>

Comment: What's your source for the "Born England 1815"? Anything you can dig into further to find your Charles Templeman's parents' names?

Comment: In cases where are trying to eliminate possibilities, each question leads to others. Such as: Do you have evidence of this family in the UK census of 1841? Was Chas a tailor by trade? Did they live in St Pancras? Could Emma actually be Amelia? Why is there such a large gap between children? Was there a daughter Margaret b 1838?

Comment: I would like to second the request for more information on the website you are talking about. Can you provide a link? Thanks

Comment: https://online.justice.vic.gov.au/bdm/index-search?action=getHistIdxSearchCriteria It is a pay per view page.
Born England is from one of the children's birth record.

Answer (score 8):

A search of the Australia Birth Index 1788-1922 on ancestry.com did not turn up any Charles Templeman born in  Australia in the vicinity of 1812. Indeed the earliest Templeman listed is Charles and Jane's daughter Clara Jane Templeman, 1849. This would indicate that this Charles Templeman was born overseas - although birth records from that early in Australia's history are surely not guaranteed to be 100% complete.

A search of the British Convict Transportation Register ([State Library of Queensland site](http://www.slq.qld.gov.au/resources/family-history/info-guides/convicts/about)) turns up 6 Templemans transported, but no Charles.

Obviously this doesn't prove anything, but if there *was* an alternative Charles Templeman, particularly one whose birth year more closely matched the death record, or whose parents' names matched, it would be evidence that this death record was *not* your man.